# detect tap on title view of MKMapAnnotationView in ios 7.0

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, mapkit

Currently I am developing one application which is having map to show.
 I am Having near by location to show using web service.
I am able to show pins on map and its callout view.
I have title and with that custom direction button on callout view. 
I want two different operation on click of callout view.

1. If rightCalloutAccessoryView is tapped then default calloutaccessoryview delegate method to be called
2. If the title is tapped then the other viewcontroller to be opened.

currently I had developed using this
[Detect tap on title of callout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8469539/detect-tap-on-title-of-callout)

It is working perfectly till ios 6.1 but not in ios 7.0
So what can be the issue?
I need your help. 
  
Thanks inadvance 
  bskania

Comment: Why not add a leftCalloutAccessoryView for the "other" action?  In the delegate method, you can check which one was tapped (left or right).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691783/ios-distinguish-between-which-callout-accessory-is-tapped for an example of using both a left and right callout accessory view.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion but if I want same as what I ad implemented for ios 6.1 what can be other option to implement it for ios 7