# How to I let MKAnnotationView to execute different method once its accessory view is tapped

Tags: ios, mapkit, mkannotationview, callout

Right now, i have implemented this delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
```

However, I would like the callout view and its left/right to trigger different methods. As of right now, tapping at the callout view and its left accessory view produces the same output. How do I differentiate between callout view being tapped or the right callout accessory gets tapped?

Comment: Do you mean this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13691783/ios-distinguish-between-which-callout-accessory-is-tapped

Comment: Thanks! This helps. Never thought of UIControl as a UIView before; however, clicking at the callout directly still triggers the same method as the rightCallOutAccessoryView. How should I refer to the callOutView directly?

Comment: UIControl is a subclass of UIView.  There's no documented/supported way to reference the callout view directly.  However, at least on iOS 7, I think tapping on the callout view itself is interpreted as a "right" callout accessory view tap.

Comment: So... there's no way to differentiate between the tapping the callout view and the right accessory view?

Comment: No easy way that I know of.  If absolutely necessary, you'd have to use a custom callout view which the SDK doesn't help you with much (set canShowCallout to NO and then show your own view in didSelectAnnotationView, etc).

Comment: Thanks @AnnaKarenina. I do not plan to implement the custom callout at the moment. Will live with the current implementation then. :)